# Sub-Basis of a Topology James Munkres

Tags: general-topology, self-learning

James Munkres defines a subbasis $\mathcal S$ for a topology on a set $X$ as a collection of subsets of $X$ whose union equals $X$. Then the topology generated by the subbasis $\mathcal S$ is defined to be the collection $\mathcal T$ of all unions of finite intersections of elements of $\mathcal S$. To prove that $\mathcal T$ is indeed a topology, one only needs to show that the collection $\mathcal B$ of all finite intersections of elements of $\mathcal S$ is a basis.

My question is what if $\mathcal S$ is a partition of $X$? Then any finite intersection of the elements of $\mathcal S$ is either $\emptyset$ or the elements of $\mathcal S$. It is clear that $\emptyset$ is not enough to generate a topology. Hence the topology is essentially generated by all the unions of the elements of $\mathcal S$, which is in fact the property of a basis rather than a subbasis. Hence, if my argument is correct, then I can conclude that if elements of $\mathcal S$ form a partition of $X$, then there is no difference between basis and subbasis. Is this right, please? Thank you!

Comment: What about $S \cap S$, for $S \in \mathcal{S}$?

Comment: @Nick Good point. Thank you. I will update my question.

Comment: @Nick Just wondering whether $S\cap S$ is valid since there is only one $S$ in $\mathcal S$. Can you intersect with yourself?

Comment: Why is there only one $S$ in $\mathcal{S}$?

Comment: @Nick Because by set theory convention, all elements in a set is unique. For example, $\{1,1,1\}=\{1\}$.

Comment: But $\mathcal{S}$ is a collection of subsets of $X$.

Comment: @Nick That is true. But $\mathcal S$ is also a set whose elements are sets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are quite right: if $\mathcal{S}$ forms a partition of the set $X$ (union all of $X$, pairwise disjoint), they actually form a base for a topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $X$, which are exactly the unions of members of $\mathcal{S}$.

Recall the characterization of base $\mathcal{B}$: $\cup \mathcal{B} = X$ and for every $B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal{B}$, for all $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$ there exists $B_3 \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B_3 \subset B_1 \cap B_2$. If $\mathcal{B}$ forms a partition, the first is automatic, and the second condition can only be satisfied when $B_1 = B_2$, as all other intersections are empty (and so the for all $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$ condition is trivially true), and then taking $B_3 = B_1 = B_2$ is enough. So a partition is a base for a topology .

In fact *any* collection of subsets of $X$ forms a subbase and the statement that the finite intersections of members of $\mathcal{S}$ form a base remains true. But by convention/logic we include the *empty* intersection (the intersection of zero members of $\mathcal{S}$), which equals $X$, so the union to $X$ is then automatically fulfilled. Of course all 1-set intersections from $\mathcal{S}$, i.e. all members of $\mathcal{S}$ are also in this, etc. Maybe Munkres wanted to avoid the whole empty intersection explanation, and his condition makes it unnecessary (but makes a subbase more restrictive).

Comment: By "any collection of subsets of $X$ forms a subbase", you mean any collection which also covers $X$, right?

Comment: @SaulBerardo no, not necessarily. The generated base always contains $X$ anyway as the intersection of the empty ( also finite) subfamily. Munkres is the one using nonstandard terminology here.

Comment: @SaulBerardo in this case that also happens to be the case. A partition covers. But it’s not necessary.

Comment: My feeling is that the phrase "In fact any collection of subsets of $X$ forms a subbase" _without the additional requirement that this collection covers $X$_ is not correct. The definition of a subbasis (as given by Munkres) requires this extra condition.

Comment: Also, notice that Munkres states in the first chapter (p. 13 on 2nd edition) that "we shall not define the intersection when $\mathcal{A}$ [the index set] is empty".  Since he didn't mention this fact when talking about subbasis, I don't think it is relevant there

Comment: @SaulBerardo Because he does *not* define it as $X$ (as is conventional) he does need his condition on a subbase, because he insists on going via a base without mentioning $X$. It's Munkres' stubbornness to follow traditions, maybe. But you could mention it, as it does hold. I just point out that most topologists in real life don't follow his approach.

Comment: thanks for your patience! However, it still seems to me the definition of subbasis given by Munkres doesn't require talking about intersections over an empty index-set at all. If we assume that the elements of $\mathcal{S}$ must be included in the basis defined as "the collection $\mathcal{B}$ of all finite intersection of elements of $\mathcal{S}$" (since any set equals its intersection with itself), the problem is gone...

Comment: ...for example, if we assume $\mathcal{S}$ is composed by a partition made of, say, two non-overlapping subsets, these two non-overlapping subsets would belong to the basis $\mathcal{B}$ defined above and then their union, which equals the whole $X$, would be included in the topology induced by this basis. Thus, no empty index-set intersection needed.

Comment: @SaulBerardo As I said, if we have a partition, their union is $X$ already (and they're pairwise disjoint) so the generated base is the partition itself (**plus** $X$ (as empty intersection) and $\emptyset$, but we could those two out of the base, it doesn't affect the topology it generates).